# Edit the <title> tag with jQuery or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have some home made blog, and when viewing blog posts I'd like to change the title tag for adding the post title, so when I use the Twitter's tweet button, it adds the new button. I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

 $(this).attr("title", "<?php echo $tagValue["title"]." - YourCloud"; ?>");

});
</script>
```

And:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 document.title = "<?php echo $tagValue["title"]." - YourCloud"; ?>";

});
</script>
```

But the Tweet Button still has the title I set up at the start, how can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
In my index.php I add the title tag, I want to modify it so when you see the source it already appears modified

Comment: to clarify, are you trying to change the page title or the title attribut of an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to set the text of the tweet, because by default the document title is tweeted. Well, you can modify the tweet button code to achieve this. See the href of the anchor element below where I added a 'text' parameter.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=any_text_you_want" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
```

More here- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Answer (score 2):

Try instead

```
$("title").text("<?php echo $tagValue['title']." - YourCloud"; ?>");
```

Comment: I'm not sure i'm understanding the question then that would update the page title. 

Is the page title the URL of the current page? i.e. blog/my-first-blog-post? and you want to set the title to my first blog post - YourCloud ?

Comment: exactly, but then I need it to make it so it changes the `<title>` tag. The TweetButton grabs that tag

Comment: See the post by @salman, you can change the src url in the anchor to set a title and append - YourCloud to that.

Comment: Why do this when `document.title = 'foo'` is so much simpler? You don't always need jQuery and it doesn't always make things easier. In this case, the script runs slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("title").html("<?php echo $tagValue['title']." - YourCloud"; ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

[document.title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.title) is what you should use to change the title of the page, f.ex:

```
document.title = 'Foo bar';
```

But it sounds like you are trying to change the title of the tweet button?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes I know this has an accepted answer - but I wasn't sure if it was exactly what he was after.

I'm not sure that anyone understands your questions properly - and after reading through the question/answers I'm still non the wiser.

Also, `document.title` over `jQuery` in this instance.

You're saying that `$("title").html("<?php echo $tagValue['title']." - YourCloud"; ?>");` is showing the original title? Well of course it is.
All the PHP is executed BEFORE the JavaScript, so the `echo $tagValue['title']` is essentially a static value throughout your JavaScript. Therefore, you're loading the same title into the title bar every time you try and change it.

By the time your PHP reaches the browser, it's no longer `$("title").html("<?php echo $tagValue['title']." - YourCloud"; ?>");`, it's `$("title").html("My Title - YourCloud");`

Unless of course I'm understanding the question wrong. You really are missing so many details. Where is `$tagValue['title']` being set - what is the value. I'm presuming that PHP is parsing your JS correctly so I won't bother asking whether you're using an external script. What do you expect the answer to be.

But from everything I've read and understood from your script - why are you changing the title with JavaScript at all. If PHP is putting a static value into your page, then you may as well just put `<title><?php echo $tagValue['title']." - YourCloud"; ?></title>` in the head of your HTML.
The only reason that I can see for the title changing with JavaScript is when an event happens that the user needs notifying about - or if you're using something like Ajax to have a dynamic site.

I'll update this post with more details if you can comment back and, well, help me/everyone to understand your question.

*EDIT:*
If you want to edit the title by pressing a button: Why not place an onclick on the button itself and just do something like:

```
function test() {
 if(document.title.indexOf(" - YourCloud")==-1){
  document.title += " - YourCloud";
 }
}
```

Not tested, but, surely that could work for you.

Comment: @zad0xsis is trying to set the text that is tweeted when someone clicks the tweet button. That text can be easily set by modifying the tweet button code, which I said in my answer. Otherwise, the document title is tweeted when someone clicks the tweet button. The tweet button loads a javascript from twitter.com and it sets the document title as the default tweet text when the document is loaded. After that even if you change document title using jQuery the tweet text won't change.